# Handle user Id from Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

I use this code to get the ID of an user that is logged in:

```
var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

My thought was to use this as an reference and add it like a integer number to a Customer table, the ID that I get in return, is not like an integer, it's looks like this:

```
ccc30b4f-2605-4151-8171-d49c30910bdc
```

I guess the ID is encrypted, but how should I do to be able to use the ID from a person that is logged in?

Comment: The Id is a `GUID` and not an `Integer`. What is the actual problem?

Comment: @JamieR I'm not sure I know that myself :) I'm learning and I'm buliding a simple webshop. When the customer click on the buy button I want the user to log in. Since I also has a Customer table, I wanted to add the users ID as a reference. Or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: If you want to reference a user then using the `UserId` would be the correct thing to do. A `GUID` is a different data type.

Comment: OK, but if I use the UserId, i get the encrypted version and I guess I cant add that to the Customer table?!

Comment: The user Id is **not** encrypted, It is the userid (ID does not always mean `int`). If you want to store a reference to the user then yes, store the UserId in your customer table.

Comment: Hmmm, but why do I get this long row of numbers and letters?! And not a plain ID like 1 ?

Comment: The UserId is not an `int` it's a `GUID`. It's a different type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: Aha, I think I get it now! This is a unique ID, so if I store that in the customer table, then I can match that customer with the the ID in the Identity table?

Comment: Correct. That is a unique reference to a specific user.

Comment: Great! So when the user is logged in, the next step would be for the customer to fill a form with billing address and other infos to add to the Customer table along with the GUID? Is this the correct way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103493/discussion-between-jamie-r-and-front-back).